# Azure API Management automation

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-management-api

I'm looking into automating the creation and configuration of an Azure API Management portal.

My current plan is to use PowerShell for this, but I'm not sure if the PowerShell API supports everything that I need to do:

- Authenticate to Azure
- Create the APIM resource
- Create APIM products
- Create API endpoints in each product from swagger definition
- Set up OAUTH
- Set e-mails templates
- Configure the developer portal (branding, wordings)
- Create roles
- Create users and assign roles to them

Can all this be achieved using the PowerShell API?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a very long question. Let me try to answer it one by one.

---

- Authentication - Yes
- Create APIM Resource - Yes - Refer [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/powershell-create-service-instance)
- Create APIM Products - Yes - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/Add-AzureRmApiManagementApiToProduct?view=azurermps-6.8.1)
- For more please refer all cmdlets - [AzureRm.APIManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.apimanagement/?view=azurermps-6.8.1)

Comment: How about rest of the things on the list? Like notifications and notification emails?